# Add array data type to sql database

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to add array data type to the postgreSQL database?

Like this :

```
   ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN new_column_name ARRAY;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ARRAY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) on any built-in or user-defined base type, enum type, or composite type like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN new_column_name INTEGER ARRAY;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f7029e74f2273ed1b474cae8969d959f)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to define the type of the array, e.g. if you want an array of integers, use `int[]`

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD COLUMN new_column_name int[];
```

(or use the `ARRAY` keyword as shown in Sebastian's answer)

For more details, [see the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html)